# Paypal-MPL IOS Sdk Getting internall error 520002 due to payment currency

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using **paypal** **parallelPayment** In my eCommerce app.In my app i am using different currency for purchase an item.

## Test case 1

If I order an item with the **"USD"** (payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";) means its work fine if works fine and my order is placed successfully

## Test case 2

If I change the payment.paymentCurrency to **"EUR"** like payment.paymentCurrency = @"EUR"; it logged in successfully and show the summary page one sec and immediately show internal error.

To illustrate the issue i have added the image below

[image]

and its display the bellow error in the console

## Error

category = Application;
errorId = 520002;
message = "Internal Error";
severity = None;

Iam struggling in this issue for long time. Please suggest me some good solution

Comment: Can you provide a correlation ID at all?  Is your account set up to be able to receive the EUR currency?

Comment: It will work if I disable the shipping means

Comment: Thank you for the update. If you could, can you create a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts with your account info that you are using, date/time stamp (with timezone) of the error, and a correlation ID from an error?  This way your account info isn't in this public forum and I'll look into the issue further for you. Please keep in mind, however, that the MPL is being deprecated in lieu of our Mobile SDKs (will deprecate once the mSDKs are up to parity) so fixes or enhancements to the MPL are a lower priority.